# как в регулярном выражении обозначаются ? и =

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

есть такая строка

```
serial/category/oneserial?id=serial-Bekstrom
```

как её полностью получить в preg_math
если я до вот этого уже добрался

```
(\w*)/(\w*)/((\w*))
```

и получаю эту строку `serial/category/oneserial` в перавом масиве то как полностью получить строку учитывая что я не зная как получить `?и =` ?

Comment: А чем функция [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php) вам не угодила?

Comment: что значит полностью получить?

Comment: @MaxTimakov ксожалению не угодило объяснять долго

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вот так:

```
(\w*)/(\w*)/(\w*)\?id=\w*-\w*
```

Спецсимволы экранируются знаком `\`(установил пред знаком вопроса). Знак `=` спецсимволом не является, его экранировать не нужно.

В некоторых типах регулярных выражений необходимо экранировать символ `/`.

Можно экранировать целую последовательность символов, заключив её между `\Q` и `\E`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gH0vA9/1 как вам такая строка?